# Are non-replacing draws from an infinite, non-shuffling pool independent?

Tags: probability

An infinite number of opaque jars are each filled with N spheres, p N of which are gold and (1 - p) N of which are tungsten (0 ≤ p < 1; N > 0). You have drawn from a jar x spheres without replacement, all of which were made of tungsten (0 < x < N). N and E[p] are constant across jars.

Should you (a) keep drawing from the same jar, (b) switch to a different jar (assuming zero switching cost) or (c) not care?

*Why I'm asking: trying to figure out if the probability of finding a BTC block is always independent between hashes. A block is "found" when the hash of the block header is below a threshold. Three variables in the block header: the nonce value, time stamp, and coinbase address. The nonce value and time stamps are in a manageably finite discrete space. The coinbase address is in a practically infinite discrete space.*

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. "Should you..." - for what purpose? What's the stopping condition?

Comment: @sashkello In order to draw a gold sphere

Comment: well, then it sounds kind of obvious: the probability of finding gold in the first sphere is higher because there is more gold to tungsten ratio there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether (i) there are exactly $pN$ gold spheres at the start in your jar, or (ii) each of the $N$ spheres had an *independent* probability $p$ of being gold when put into the jar.

In case (i), you should stick with the jar you have partly emptied.  The probability the next sphere you draw from it is gold is  $\frac{pN}{N-x}$ which is greater than the probability $p$ that a sphere drawn from another jar is gold.

In case (ii), it does not matter.  The probability that your next sphere is gold is $p$ whether you draw it from the same jar or a different jar.